# Resizing PDF document in Adobe Acrobat Pro

Tags: resize, print-production, adobe-acrobat

I received a 322 page PDF at work and was asked to have it resized with everything scaled proportionally to updated size. Is there any way to do this in Adobe Acrobat? I found a way to resize the page by using the crop pages tool and entering custom size but it doesn't look like you can scale to fit?

[image]

This is the Acrobat Version Im working on
[image]

Comment: In Acrobat Pro, look under tools > print production > preflight > profiles > fixes > scale pages to specified size. This is the first item from a web search for "batch scale resize in Acrobat Pro". Did you try this ?